JQuery error in Electron: '$ is not defined'
I am building a Flask web app using pyinstaller, and I've been trying to get it to work on Electron. The project uses jQuery and Bootstrap along with a couple of other libraries.
The problem is that I've been getting two errors:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
($.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = transitionEndEmulator)
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
This prevents me from using certain features of the website.
Things I've tried:

Tried the solution from Question [#32621988]

<!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>

<!-- normal script imports etc  -->
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>    

<!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>


Ensure jQuery loads. It loads from /bootstrap/static/jquery.min.js.
Add the lines nodeIntegration = true and contextIsolation = false.
When running the Flask executable and opening the website on my browser, the $ is not defined error does not show up and works correctly.
Checked the order of imports for jQuery and other scripts.

Some help would be deeply appreciated!

How did you determine that jQuery is loading?

When I look at the network tab of the developer console, I can see a GET request for jquery which happens successfully.

Don't tell me down here. Tell the community in your question. Please take the [tour].

You can import it at the bottom of the body element like this::
<body>
    <!-- Other body content -->

    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('{PATH_OF_JQUERY}/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');</script>
</body>


What problem does this solve?
